# "No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser"

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I connect to machine-1 via ssh in Windows, then connect to machine-2 from machine-1, and finally connect to machine-3(linux operating system) from machine-2. I have installed jupyter notebook in machine-3 and add
`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter` and
`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook` into my .bashrc file.

In machine-3, I run pyspark under the directory `/home/user_name` by typing `pyspark` in command line, I get the following messages from notebook:

```
[I 16:45:29.491 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 16:45:29.495 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user_name
[I 16:45:29.495 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:45:29.495 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=19ced6aaec6f3ff0d9679ab766b893503381c3987e8ab64e
[I 16:45:29.495 NotebookApp]  or http://x.x.x.x:8889/?token=19ced6aaec6f3ff0d9679ab766b893503381c3987e8ab64e
[I 16:45:29.495 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 16:45:29.501 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 16:45:29.501 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///home/user_name/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-57150-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8889/?token=19ced6aaec6f3ff0d9679ab766b893503381c3987e8ab64e
    or http://x.x.x.x:8889/?token=19ced6aaec6f3ff0d9679ab766b893503381c3987e8ab64e
```

From the above messages, jupyter notebook is obviously running somewhere, but the problem is I can't open both the two URLs using browser in my Windows system.

I have tried replacing x.x.x.x with the IP of machine-3, but still can't open the two URLs in Windows.

Is that because there is no browser installed in machine-3?

thanks very much for your help!

Comment: There may be some firewall protecting access to machine-3 from machine-1, if you have to go through machine-2 to access it. That way, you would never be able to access your notebook via `http://x.x.x.x:8889/?token=19ced6aaec6f3ff0d9679ab766b893503381c3987e8ab64e`, with `x.x.x.x` the IP address of machine-3.

Comment: If my above comment is correct, then the near-only way to access machine-3 from machine-1 would be to use `ssh` tunneling. Which is not immediately fun and/or obvious if you've never played around with that. And what you would need to do for that, will likely depend on what you are using to run `ssh` from machine-1.

Comment: Additional question: does machine-3's IP address start with `192.168` or `172` or `10`? Because that would be an internal private network, and you can't use that address anyway (firewall or not) to access machine-3 from machine-1.

Comment: @9769953 Yes, machine-3's IP address start with `10`. Now I know the reason I can't open the notebook, very informative answer! 3Q(which means thank you)

Comment: Note that I do mean `10.x.y.z`, not something like `108.x.y.z` or `106.x.y.z`.

Comment: I got you at the first time, machine-3's IP address does like `10.x.y.z`.

Comment: Ok. Since that is indeed a private network, I think your best option would be to search around how to set up some nested ssh-tunnel, starting from Windows and through *nix. There's too little info to help you out with that, but since you know how you ssh into machine-2 and machine-3, you're in the best position to find it out yourself.

Comment: Yeah good suggestion, I will try it out.